# separate fixed-size animation sheet into texture atlas

Tags: sprites, spritesheet, texture-atlas

I'd like to separate a 64px x 512px spritesheet into eight 64px 64px images in Adobe photoshop cs 5 so I can use a Texture Packer image atlas rather than a fixed spritesheet.

[image]

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Not really a game development question, but you can look up Photoshop Scripts and I'm sure there's one that'll do the trick. You'd probably have to customize it to your sprite sheet's size.

Comment: Another thought: http://superuser.com/questions/206268/photoshop-how-to-save-selection-to-png

Comment: You can just write a program to do this for you. Open the .png and provide a pixel stride. Then save out all the pngs.